# Update child gameobject positions when rotating parent gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner and I'm currently trying to create a 3D Tetris. Since 1-2 Weeks im trying to rotate my Tetromino properly, but it's not working the way I want.
[image]

So this is my "T" Tetromino. It's made of 4 Cubes, which are combined with an empty gameobject like this:

[image]

When I rotate the "T" gameobject with `transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90)`, optically every cube moves, but not really. There is a blue dot on the first Picture. When i rotate my gameobject, it rotates around this point. After the rotation, every cube gets its new `transform.position` expect the middle one. Optically it moves one unit, but its `transform.position` doesn't change.

The same with the other figures. There is always one Cube, which `transform.position` doesn't update. I kinda know why its position doesn't change, but i still don't know what to do.

I tried many stuff, but i failed. Summarized I want my gameobject to rotate and update its position. Is there a way to do this?

Best regards

Comment: A child gameobjects position is relative to the parent. So, if you're rotating "T" then it's childrens position will always stay the same relative to itself. Also, I believe your blue dot should be in the dead center of the entire object. Where your pivot is located now is more like a "hinge" when you really want it to act more like a central rotation.

Comment: @BrandonMiller thx for your fast answer. The `transform.localPosition` will be the same, but `transform.position` is `WorldSpace`, so it chages. Only not for that one Cube. Pivot: I did not place it there. It's was just there and i don't know, how to move it.

Comment: The blue dot is the location of your T gameobject. Unchild the objects, move "T" to the center, and then re-child. As far as transform.position not updating, I'm really not sure.